I am facing JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: {"status":60,"value":"[object HTMLButtonElement] has no size and location"
when i run headless = True i get this error
JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: {"status":60,"value":"[object HTMLButtonElement] has no size and location"}
  (Session info: chrome-headless-shell=124.0.6367.119)

but works fine when headless = False
can some one fix the issue in my script, I am trying to webscrape below is the code where error triggers
 try:
    select_store = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//button[@class="cc-btn cc-btn--secondaryC js-selectStore"][@data-storename="FIRENZE NOVOLI"]')
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.save_screenshot('click7.png')
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(select_store).click(select_store).perform()
    driver.save_screenshot('click8.png')
except StaleElementReferenceException as e:
    driver.save_screenshot('click9.png')
    select_store = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//button[@class="cc-btn cc-btn--secondaryC js-selectStore"][@data-storename="FIRENZE NOVOLI"]')
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.save_screenshot('click10.png')
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(select_store).click(select_store).perform()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.save_screenshot('click11.png')

I am trying to run code in headless= true without error

What does your Selenium driver settings/options look like and have you tried adding the window size? For example, options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")

@Pramesh Thank you!!! This fixed my selenium script running in a docker container.
